# How to retrieve data from local storage and display it on form's check box or dropdown menu in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a form which contains radio check and dropdown menu after selection and check data goes to local storage  and there is button for update when click it back again to the form again filled by data from local storage but I can't make the radio check be checked according to data also the option not select in the selected menu.
code should be in JavaScript only

```
        <select class="country" >
            <option value="0">Choose Your Country</option>
            <option value="1">UAE</option>
            <option value="2">USA</option>
            <option value="3">UK</option>
        </select>
        <p id="type">Gender:</p>
            <input type="radio" value="male" name="gender" class="gender">
            <label for="male">Male</label>
            <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender" class="gender">
            <label for="female">Female</label>
```

Comment: So what did you attempt? Where is the code that sets the storage?

Answer (score 1):

For checkbox

```js
let checkboxes = [checkboxOne, checkboxTwo, checkBoxThree];
let checkboxLabels = [labelOne, labelTwo, labelThree];

for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (window.localStorage.getItem('checkboxValue') === checkboxLabels[i].textContent) {
        checkboxes[i].setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
    }
}
```

For drop down

```js
let options = [optionOne, optionTwo, optionThree];

for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    if (window.localStorage.getItem('dropdownValue') === options[i].value) {
        options[i].setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
    }
}
```

Instead of putting elements inside arrays, you can use `querySelectorAll`

```js
let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('#form input[type="radio"]');
```

Comment: I made it with the answer you provided it was useful . thanks i added  options[i].setAttribute('selected', 'selected') ,  checkboxes[i].setAttribute('checked','checked');

Answer (score 0):

You can access localStorage on windows object. And change values using queryselectors or pass a function to the value.

```
document.querySelector(<selector>).<propperty you want to set> = window.localStorage.<value tou want to retieve>
```